# String comparison in Vimscript

Tags: vim, string-comparison

I'm using Vim to read man and I'm trying to set up a script in my vimrc that will display NERDTree unless I'm reading from a man page.

I've got the following in vimrc:

```
" This is needed because $MANPATH wasn't set in my environment    
let $MANPATH=substitute(system("manpath"),"\n","","") 

if (match(expand("%:p:h"),$MANPATH) == -1)
    echo ("manpath is: ".$MANPATH)
    echo ("path is: ".expand("%:p:h"))
    echo ("match: ".match(expand("%:p:h"),$MANPATH))
    " Load NERDTree here
endif
```

When I run vim normally, it works as expected:

```
andrey@Andrey-P:~$ vim file.txt
manpath is: /usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
path is: /home/andrey
match: -1
```

However, opening a man page returns this:

```
andrey@Andrey-P:~$ man vim
manpath is: /usr/local/man:/usr/local/share/man:/usr/share/man
path is: /usr/share/man
match: -1
```

One would expect this to be a fairly straightforward match to make, but it doesn't seem to work. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It looks like you've got the arguments to `match()` the wrong way around. The first argument should be the expression to be searched (`$MANPATH` in your case) and the second argument should be search pattern.

See `:help match()` for a full description of the function.

Comment: Ouch. Been using languages in which all string comparison functions are the opposite - this is still not an excuse though. Thank you for your help!